# Making video footage look old

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Solely in Blender, I'd like to take my animated render (which presumably is in black and white) and make it look as if it was video footage taken many years ago—the classic little lines and dots and smudges on that sort of thing.

How would this be accomplished?

Comment: have you followed some tuto about the VSE? there is one explaining this kind of effects, you put some layers on your video and change their transparency with noise for example

Comment: I haven't seen any tutorials on the subject, no.

Comment: for example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ug19fijOZ-4

Comment: I'd mess with the Color Management settings under the Scene tab in the properties panel for lighting. Change the view to Filmic or Film with low contrast. For the old look, I'd use the EasyFX addon. You have many options to get it how you want. For the lines and dots, just composite an image that had the dots and lines on top of the video.